# Add delay to CCSpawn sequence

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to add a delay in a CCSpawn sequence, I want the fadeOut to start slightly after the moveBy has started rather than them both happening at the same time.

```
CCSpawn *anim = [CCSpawn actions:
    [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.5 position:ccp(0.0,50.0)],
    [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.2],
    [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5],nil];
```

The CCDelayTime in the middle seems to have no effect.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
id move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.5 position:ccp(0.0,50.0)];
id fade = [CCSequence actions: [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.2], 
                               [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5], nil];

CCSpawn *anim = [CCSpawn actions:move, fade, nil];
```

(just put them in their own variables so it is a little easier to read).